# struct returning character array printing a value twice

Tags: c, arrays, linux, struct

It's a simple program in which function abc is returning an array. But the output is

```
Thanks
abcdefThanks
```

Why so? I want *Thanks* to be printed only once.
Also I need to take the size of *a* as 6. In this program, it doesn't matter but I am doing raw socket programming where I need it. size = 6 is declared in the predefined header files there.  How can I implement it?

```
char *abc()
{
    unsigned char *ch;
    unsigned char a[7],c[6];
    strncpy(a,"Thanks",strlen("Thanks"));
    strncpy(c,"abcdef",strlen("abcdef"));
    ch=malloc(50);
    memset(ch,0,50);
    memcpy(ch,&a,strlen(a));
    memcpy(ch+strlen(a)+1,&c,strlen(c));
    return ch;
}
int main()
{
    char *a;
    a=abc();
    printf("\n%s\n",a);
    printf("\n%s\n",(a+7));
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Is really you got out put like this? because `a` will print `Thanks�abcdef` and `a+7` will `abcdef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `strlen(a)` is not stopping where you think it should because there's no zero-terminator and garbage memory is spoiling your result. **strlen(string) doesn't include the count of a zero-terminator**

You should rather do the following (look at the comments)

```
char *abc()
{
    char *ch;
    char a[7],c[7];
    strncpy(a,"Thanks",strlen("Thanks")); // Watch out, strlen(string) doesn't include null terminator
    a[6] = '\0'; // Prevent garbage from uninitialized memory to pester your ch and strlen(a)
    strncpy(c,"abcdef",strlen("abcdef"));
    c[6] = '\0';
    ch=malloc(50);
    memset(ch,0,50);
    memcpy(ch,&a,strlen(a));
    memcpy(ch+strlen(a),&c,strlen(c)); // No -1 because you want to cut the terminator off
    return ch;
}
int main()
{
    char *a;
    a=abc();
    printf("\n%s\n",a);
    printf("\n%s\n",(a+7));
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The above was compiled with C++ but it should pretty much be the same with a few adjustments.

Here's with a memory-like dumping where # means garbage

```
char *abc()
{
    char *ch;
    char a[7],c[7];
    strncpy(a,"Thanks",strlen("Thanks")); // Watch out, strlen(string) doesn't include null terminator
    // a = "Thanks##################################.."
    a[6] = '\0'; // Prevent garbage from uninitialized memory to pester your ch and strlen(a)
    // a = "Thanks\0############################"
    strncpy(c,"abcdef",strlen("abcdef"));
    // c = "abcdef############################"
    c[6] = '\0';
    // c = "abcdef\0############################"
    ch=malloc(50);
    // ch = "###############################"
    memset(ch,0,50);
    // ch = "000000000000000000000000000000"
    memcpy(ch,&a,strlen(a));
    // ch = "Thanks000000000000000000000000"
    memcpy(ch+strlen(a),&c,strlen(c)); // No -1 because you want to cut the terminator off
    // ch = "Thanksabcdef00000000000000000"
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Sorry, fixed and +1 :)

Comment: @unwind nice to see your comment. you always keep correcting everyone on this. Well done!! Thanks :)

Comment: @user3433848 It's a bit of an uphill struggle, but I try. :)

Comment: @DavidKernin Thanks a lot. Wonderful Explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to zero terminate your strings by appending a 0 byte.

```
unsigned char a[7], c[7]; // 7 = 6+1 since "Thanks" and "abcdef" have 6 bytes
strncpy (a, "Thanks", 6);
a[6] = (char)0;
strncpy (c, "abcdef", 6);
c[6] = (char)0;
```

your `c` string was too short and not explicitly 0-ended. So your `strlen(c)`  is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: `(char) 0` is a rather weird way of writing `'\0'`, in my opinion.